# How to get/enable the new locally integrated menus (LIM) inside of the windows titlebar?

Tags: unity, 14.04, locally-integrated-menus

I hear about this new feature, but don't know how to enable it.  It look as this
[image]

Do anyone have any idea how to enable this?  And is it possible to get it on other Desktop Environments like XFCE?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's in the System Settings, under the appearance tab, behaviour. Right click on the desktop, click "Change Desktop Background", and then look in the Behavior tab:

[image]